# Can manually set up Ethernet but not WiFi communication using C program

Tags: c, sockets, networking, wifi, ioctl

I have written a **C** program that can set an IP address and a subnet mask of the user's choice for any available network interface. I am able to establish communication between two computers **connected to each other by an ethernet cable** by simply using this program to configure an IP and a netmask for each of them. However, this method does not work on the WiFi interface.

Here's what I did when the two laptops were **connected by an ethernet cable** (`inet_config` is my **C** program that sets an IP and a netmask for any network interface).

***First Laptop:***

```
inet_config  eth0  192.168.1.0  255.255.255.0
```

***Second Laptop:***

```
inet_config  eth0  192.168.1.1  255.255.255.0
```

This sets the IP addresses of the ethernet interfaces on the first and second laptops to `192.168.1.0` and `192.168.1.1` respectively. The subnet masks of the ethernet interfaces on both laptops are set to `255.255.255.0`.

Now, I am able to use `nc` to establish communication between the two laptops. However, the connection is not established if I use WiFi interfaces instead of ethernet. I found that when I use WiFi, the `connect()` syscall returns the error `EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)`. Can anyone tell me what I need to do in order to get this running on WiFi?

The source code for `inet_config` is here:

```
/* inet_config.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define _COMMAND_NAME   argv[0]
#define _INTERFACE_NAME argv[1]
#define _INET_ADDRESS   argv[2]
#define _SUBNET_MASK    argv[3]

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int sockfd, ioctl_result, inet_conv_result, subnet_conv_result;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct sockaddr_in inet_addr, subnet_mask;

    /* Check argument count */

    if(argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s interface_name ip_addr subnet_mask\n", _COMMAND_NAME);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Initialization */

    bzero((char *)&ifr, sizeof(ifreq));
    bzero((char *)&inet_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    bzero((char *)&subnet_mask, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, _INTERFACE_NAME);

    /* Prepare inet_address and subnet_mask structures */

    inet_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_conv_result = inet_pton(AF_INET, _INET_ADDRESS, &(inet_addr.sin_addr));

    if(inet_conv_result == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_pton: Invalid IPv4 address format\n");
        exit(_EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(inet_conv_result < 0)
    {
        perror("inet_pton");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    subnet_mask.sin_family = AF_INET;
    subnet_conv_result = inet_pton(AF_INET, _SUBNET_MASK, &(subnet_mask.sin_addr));

    if(subnet_conv_result == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_pton: Invalid subnet mask format\n");
        exit(_EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(subnet_conv_result < 0)
    {
        perror("inet_pton");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Open socket for network device configuration */

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Call ioctl to configure network devices */

    memcpy(&(ifr.ifr_addr), &inet_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)); // Set IP address
    ioctl_result = ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSIFADDR, &ifr);
    if(ioctl_result < 0)
    {
        perror("SIOCSIFADDR");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memcpy(&(ifr.ifr_addr), &subnet_mask, sizeof(struct sockaddr)); //Set subnet mask
    ioctl_result = ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSIFNETMASK, &ifr);
    if(ioctl_result < 0)
    {
        perror("SIOCSIFNETMASK");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Network devices configured\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is Wi-Fi connection mode [ad-hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) or [Access Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point)?

Comment: @Dmitry From what I read on the links you included, what I want to set up is an ad-hoc network. It does not include routers. Only two computers are supposed to be connected here. What I did was manually set an IP and netmask for two laptops on their wireless interfaces. I then made one of the two laptops transmit packets whose destination was the IP address of the other computer. NOTHING ELSE WAS DONE. I got an error message as described in my post. If I do exactly the same thing but use wired interfaces instead and connect an ethernet cable to the ports on each laptop, the same program works.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need set up your Wi-Fi card to ad-hoc mode on both computers. You can set up IP address and netmask after that.

Comment: Yes, look at [Wireless Tools](http://www.labs.hpe.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html)  iwconfig.c.